# extracting fields from a text

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

according to the following file

- the script to print the first and the 3rd fields from each record on 
  the screen.
- just the 2nd field from each record and store it in a file.txt
- print the 2nd field of the lines that contain uppercase characters.

> 27,purple,dinosaur,136
>
> 152,pink,Elephant,136

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, '{print $1,$3}' inputfile.txt 
awk -F, '{print $2}' inputfile.txt > file.txt
awk -F, '/[[:upper:]]/ {print $2}' inputfile.txt
```

Good luck on your assignment. Hopefully the TA won't find this post.

Comment: `man awk` says `-F fs   --field-separator fs    Use fs for the input field separator (the value of the FS predefined variable).` In other words it decides how to split the lines into fields.

Comment: that was my problem,and if i want to print the 3rd column of the list sorted in ascending way what should i add?